# How to insert variables with a select with multiple conditions SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to insert variables with a select with multiple conditions, suppose A function returns a temp table, and i want to populate other table, but what is the query to do something like

```
INSERT INTO @table (La, Lb, Qaa, Qab,Qbb) 
   SELECT items 
   FROM dbo.SOME_FUNCTION() 
   WHERE Condition for La 
     AND condition for Lb 
     AND condition for Qaa 
     AND condition for Qab 
     AND condition for Qbb...
```

Well, the code I'm doing with one answer looks like this:

```
Declare @table TABLE
(
    La   varchar(80),
    Lb   varchar(80),
    Qaa  varchar(80),
    Qab  varchar(80),
    Qbb  varchar(80)
)

INSERT INTO @table (La, Lb, Qaa, Qab,Qbb)
    SELECT  a.La,
            a.Lb,
            a.Qaa,
            a.Qab,
            a.Qbb
    FROM   dbo.function(@somevar) a 
    WHERE   a.itemindex =  1
    AND     a.itemindex =  3 
    AND     a.itemindex =  5 
    AND     a.itemindex =  7 
    AND     a.itemindex =  9
```

But I get an error,

Sorry, I corrected it but still getting error

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure NLQ_1, Line 189
Invalid column name 'La'.
```

Why is it wrong, all column names La, Lb, Qaa,...

Comment: You will have to clear this up a little. Are you trying to insert data into a table based on values that are already in that table, or filtered/where clause based on the values returned from your Table Function?

Comment: You are inserting 1 column into a table of 5.

Comment: I want to insert data from a result that is in another temp table, you are right when you say filtering, because, the temp table is very huge!, so I want to select 5 values and insert them in a table with 5 elements

Comment: well, @The Scrum Meister  is it convenient to have only one column and insert 5 values?, how does that query look like??

Comment: What does the temp table look like? the query should be `SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4,Col5 FROM ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think the error message is about the `La` that is being selected from the function (`a.La`), not about the `La` that is being inserted to.

Second, there's an issue with the WHERE filter:

```
WHERE   a.itemindex =  1
AND     a.itemindex =  3 
AND     a.itemindex =  5 
AND     a.itemindex =  7 
AND     a.itemindex =  9
```

It is interpreted like this: '[select rows] where `a.itemindex` is equal to 1 and *at the same time* it's equal to 3 and, likewise, to 5 and so on.' You would rightfully think that it can never be true.

You were probably thinking about the condition as applied to all rows *in general*: 'get me these rows *and* these *and* these...'. But rather you should think of the condition as applied to every *single row*. Consider this: 'select every single row where `a.itemindex` is equal to 1 **or** it is equal to 3 **or** to 5 etc.'. That way you would come up with a correct filter condition, specifically this:

```
WHERE   a.itemindex =  1
OR      a.itemindex =  3 
OR      a.itemindex =  5 
OR      a.itemindex =  7 
OR      a.itemindex =  9
```

But you can simplify it even further. How do you like it put this way: 'where `a.itemindex` is one of the following: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9'? And SQL has a boolean operation for that too, it's called `IN` ('IN this list:'). And here's what you would eventually get:

```
WHERE   a.itemindex IN (1, 3, 5, 7, 9)
```

Marvellous, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

When declaring a table, just don't use any "as" keywords:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    La   varchar(80),
    Lb   varchar(80),
    Qaa  varchar(80),
    Qab  varchar(80),
    Qbb  varchar(80)
)
```

That's all that's wrong with your code...

Answer (score 0):

Well if I understand you correctly, you need to try something like

```
INSERT INTO @table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
SELECT  a.col1,
        a.col2,
        a.col3,
        a.col4,
        a.col5
FROM    dbo.Your_Function() a
WHERE   a.colx = condition1
AND     a.coly = condition2
AND     a.colz = condition3
```

The WHERE logic will be used against the results from the function, and you need to specify the columns you wish to insert to and from.

**EDIT:**

Declare the variable table as

```
Declare @table TABLE (     
    La    varchar(80),     
    Lb    varchar(80),     
    Qaa   varchar(80),     
    Qab   varchar(80),     
    Qbb   varchar(80) 
)
```